# Parsing JSON data into UITableView sections ends up duplicating and showing wrong sections

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have my app fetching the JSON data and displaying data, but when I try to do it in sections, I'm getting duplicates per section and too many sections. The goal is for each state to be a section, with each bonus for that state listed underneath. This is the code I currently have:

ViewController:

```
import UIKit
import os.log

class BonusListViewController: UITableViewController {

    var bonuses = [JsonFile.JsonBonuses]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //MARK: Trigger JSON Download
        downloadJSON {
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Table View Configuration
    // MARK: Table view data source
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        print("Found \(bonuses.count) sections.")
        return bonuses.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("Found \(bonuses[section].bonusCode.count) rows in section.")
        return bonuses[section].bonusCode.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        cell.textLabel?.text = bonuses[indexPath.section].name.capitalized
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetail", sender: self)
    }
    // MARK: - Table View Header
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 30
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return bonuses[section].state
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 3
    }

    // MARK: Functions
    // MARK: - Download JSON from ToH webserver
    func downloadJSON(completed: @escaping () -> ()) {
        let url = URL(string: "http://tourofhonor.com/BonusData.json")
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { [weak self] (data, response, error) in
            if error == nil {
                do {
                    let posts = try JSONDecoder().decode(JsonFile.self, from: data!)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completed()
                    }
                    print("JSON Version \(posts.meta.version) loaded.")
                    print(posts.bonuses.map {$0.bonusCode})
                    self?.bonuses = posts.bonuses
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        //reload table in the main queue
                        self?.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("JSON Download Failed")
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }

    // MARK: - Navigation

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? BonusDetailViewController {
            destination.bonus = bonuses[(tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!]
        }
    }
}
```

The JsonFile.swift is just a struct:

```
import Foundation

struct JsonFile: Codable {
    struct Meta: Codable {
        let fileName: String
        let version: String
    }
    struct JsonBonuses: Codable {
        let bonusCode: String
        let category: String
        let name: String
        let value: Int
        let city: String
        let state: String
        let flavor: String
        let imageName: String
    }
    let meta: Meta
    let bonuses: [JsonBonuses]
}
```

The JSON file contains two states and 9 entries total. My print statements show that it found 9 sections with 3 rows in each section. When I try to set the `return bonuses.count` to something like `return bonuses.state.count`, I get an error that says "Value of type '[JsonFile.JsonBonuses]' has no member 'state'." But there is clearly a "state" item in my struct.

Comment: You need an array of arrays to have sectioned data. You only have one array. You need to organize your data properly. Note that `bonuses[section].bonusCode` gives you a `String`. `bonuses[section].bonusCode.count` gives you the number of characters in that string.

Comment: I have full control of the JSON data as well, so what would be the best way to organize the data so I can properly use sections (if it helps my next task is to add searching and filtering, in case the data should be organized differently to accommodate that as well).

Comment: Why do you need sections? What does each section represent? Answer that first. Then you can organize your `bonuses` array into sections.

Comment: Each bonus is located in a specific state, so the sections are to organize all the bonuses by state for easier use by the users.

Comment: Could I do this by using Array(set() somehow, maybe with the map function? I'm correctly parsing the JSON, so it would seem "look at the JSON Data, group by State, then display each unique state" isn't an amazingly complex function.

Comment: Nothing about your JSON parsing needs to change. Your just need to build an array of arrays where the top-level arrays are the states and the inner arrays are the `JsonBonuses` associated with each state.

Comment: @rmaddy Do I need to add that to the struct or to my viewController?